# Get Your Life Together

Tags: riddle, wordplay, steganography

> Push me down
>   and I'll grow.
>   Confess our secret
>   and I'll go.
>
> I am the one
>   that hides within
>   the silencer known
>   as the guillotine.
>
> I punish the
>   ones with heart
>   and strip away
>   their mirth.
>
> Only talk to me
>   if you are insane.
>   I'm dangerous, but
>   clearly not inane.
>
> Who am I?

Hint 1

> I am a form e when set in motion.

Hint 2

> I lay concealed in another form in the title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you:

> Guilt?

Push me down
and I'll grow.

> The more you push down the more guilty you feel?

Confess our secret
and I'll go.

> Confess you're guilty instead

I am the one
that hides within
the silencer known
as the guillotine.

> the word guilt can be form with letters from guillotine.

I punish the
ones with heart
and strip away
their mirth.

> The more guilty you'll feel, yes

Only talk to me
if you are insane.
I'm dangerous, but
clearly not inane.

> You're guilty but you're not insane?

Who am I?

> Guilt

Hint 1:

> Motion to Adjudicate Guilt?  EDIT: Guilt is a form of 'e'motion (credits to Clangorous Chimera)

Hint 2:

> Again the word Guilt can be form with letters from title.

Comment: Yep! Gylt is the olden day spelling of guilt!

Comment: Gylt?  Woot you learn something new everyday =D

Comment: O and also Hint 1 was: e set in motion is emotion :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> the letter S?

*Push me down

    and I'll grow.*

> The letter S looks a bit like a spring, which when compressed will only grow again afterwards. (OK, this is a bit dodgy - probably there's supposed to be some wordplay here. Bear with me.)

*Confess our secret

    and I'll go.*

> Not sure about this.

*I am the one

    that hides within

    the silencer known

    as the guillotine.*

> Presumably this refers to some S-containing word for an execution device.

*I punish the

    ones with heart

    and strip away

    their mirth.*

> Add an S to LAUGHTER (mirth) and it becomes SLAUGHTER (punishment for those with the heart to laugh).

*Only talk to me

    if you are insane.

    I'm dangerous, but

    clearly not inane.*

> Add an S to INANE (which the subject is not) and it becomes INSANE (which involves the subject).

Comment: Not exactly but that works surprisingly well for some of those stanzas!

Comment: Hehe. I actually tried at something similar, but with the letter T (push down on the horizontal line and it becomes a +, there's a T in "guillotine", "secret", "heart" and "mirth", etc)

Comment: Hmmm I'm not sure how this works? Do I reveal my answer after a period of time?

Comment: @ClangorousChimera Better to add (spoilertagged) hints to the question before revealing the answer. See [this meta post](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2799/5373) about the same issue.